# Existence map in C++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I want something like an [std::map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C++%29), but I only want to see if the item exists or not, I don't actually need a key AND a value.  What should I use?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like you need a [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Answer (score 7):

If you want the same type of behavior as `std::map`, then you want `std::set`.

If you are mixing insert/delete and query operations, then `std::set` is probably the best choice. However, if you can populate the set first and then follow it with the queries, it might be worth looking at using `std::vector`, sorting it, and then using a binary search to check for existence in the vector.

Comment: Good point: the set has the disadvantage of dynamically allocating each node apart, causing more cache misses during lookup, while the vector might just fit in the processor's cache (provided it's small enough).

Comment: I assume that the alternative advice for searching a sorted `std::vector` is offered because it would yield a performance improvement when working with 'large' sets. If so, it would be interesting to know how large a set should be before giving up the ease-of-use of `std::map`.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need existence only, and not even an order, you need an `unordered_set`. It is available from your favorite C++0x vendor or [boost.org](http://boost.org).

Answer (score 2):

If your data is numerical you can use an std::vector which is optimized for space:

```
D:\Temp>type vectorbool.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        vector<bool> vb(10);
        vb[5] = true;

        for (vector<bool>::const_iterator ci = vb.begin(); ci != vb.end(); ++ci) {
                cout << *ci << endl;
        }
}

D:\Temp>cl /nologo /W4 /EHsc vectorbool.cpp
vectorbool.cpp

D:\Temp>vectorbool.exe
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: In Effective STL, Scott Meyers advises to avoid using std::vector<bool> because it does not work the same way as other std::vectors. Some discussion on it here: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98

Comment: Yup, that's something to keep in mind. Don't use vector<bool> for anything but simple cases.

Comment: The vector will not be efecient of the data is sparse or significanlty far from 0 or includes negative values

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at [`stl::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) for what you need. A [`stl::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) is another option.

It will depend on how you need to use the information that would define which of these is better. A `set` is a sorted data structure, insertion, find and deletion take O(LOG N) time. But if you need to **iterate** over all the values that you have marked for "existence" then the `set` is the way to go.

If you only need to mark and lookup the **fact** that something is a member of a set then the `bitset` might be better for you. Insertion, find and delete only takes O(1), but you can only collect `int` values. Iterating over all the marked values will take O(N) as you need to go through the whole set to find the members that are set to `true`. You can use it in concert with a [stl::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) to map from the values you have to the numerical values the `bitset` needs.

Look at the operations that you need to perform with the values in your set and you should be able to choose the appropriate data structure

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using std::map for the desired purpose.

To check if a particular item (of key type) exists in the map or not, you can use following code:

```
if (mapObj.count(item) != 0)
{
   // item exists
}
```

As answered earlier, std::set will do the job as well. Interestingly both, set and map are represented as Trees internally.

Comment: Prefer this: if (mapObj.find(item) != mapObj.end())

Answer (score 1):

If the key IS the value, then you might also consider a "bloom filter" rather than a set.

Comment: Only if you can tolerate false positives.

Comment: @Constantin, yup that's true.